# Como instalar o Plugin do TypeScript no Sublime Text 3?

Tags: git, typescript, sublime-text-3

Estou tentando instalar o plugin no Sublime Text 3, e para isto eu fiz os passos:

- Instalei o [**GIT**](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git)
- Executei os comandos disponíveis [aqui](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Sublime-Plugin) no terminal do GIT.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Pressionei `Control+Shift+P` para ver se encontrava o `TypeScript`, mas não aparece nada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- **Há algo que eu deixei pra trás?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tente seguir esse passo a passo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você me salvou dessa, fiquei feliz com isto :). Grato @Nando!